# "No module named 'lab_utils_common'"

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, sigmoid

I was trying to run this program below but it's showing the error `"No module named 'lab_utils_common'"`, what can I do to solve this problem?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lab_utils_common import  plot_data, sigmoid, dcl

plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')
```

Comment: have you installed that library?

Comment: Is lab_utils_common a local file or a library that you've installed?

Answer (score 0):

*lab_utils_common* package is either not publicly available or not actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible scenarios:

- `lab_utils_common` is a published package, but not installed. Use `pip` or `conda` to install.
- `lab_utils_common` is supposed to be a local module written to `lab_utils_common.py`, but is missing. See more on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) if interested.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this file and I think it worked for me:

https://github.com/MeteAslan/Utils/blob/main/lab_utils_common.py

Give it a try

Comment: this worked, I can verify  it, just import the required files needed. On the safety of it, I cannot verify, but I tried this. Was able to get the labs to work on my own notebook.

Answer (score 0):

For those  who have signed up for the Coursera AI/ML Course by Andrew Ng and want to backup the labs for personal reference at a later date, read on to see how to do it.

As this is my first time using Coursera, I wasn't sure if I would have access to it at a later date.

To make a backup,of all files required to run the labs just click
'Lab Files'

1. open folder
2. copy  all content.
3. place in your folder with the labs on your local computer.
4. to save the labs go to the file -> download as -> Notebook option.

Refer to attached image as a reference point.
[image]